# Swift: How to query an external database to perform login?

Tags: php, ios, database, swift

I'm very new to Swift and iOS and for an exam I am developing a little iOS app. First thing to do is login: in my view controller I have 2 text fields (login, password) and a "Sign in" button. I created a swift User Class with attributes (according to fields stored in database). Then I created a login service swift class where (following a Youtube tutorial) there are these two important methods:

```
func getUser(username:String, password:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    self.settings.webServerLoginURL = "\(self.settings.webServerLoginURL)?username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    println(self.settings.webServerLoginURL)
    self.requestLogin(self.settings.webServerLoginURL, callback: callback)

}

func requestLogin(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) {
        (data, response, error) in
        var error:NSError?
        var response = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary
        callback(response)

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

where the URL is supposed to be something like this:

```
localhost:8888/excogitoweb/loginM.php?username=xxx&password=xxx
```

Now I would like to try this stuff and so in my view controller swift file I have linked the button to the following method:

```
@IBAction func doLogin(sender : AnyObject) {
    self.service = LoginService()
    self.service.getUser(self.userTextField.text, self.passwordTextField.text)
}
```

The things I am not understanding is how to call that function, whose third argument should be a callback, and overall how to manage with response data to check if login is corrected: if so the php file should return (after querying the database) user's info with

```
echo json_encode()
```

and so I should control if the returned data is empty or not. 
Can you help me please or link some more userful tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

For the callback, let Xcode help you with its autocomplete feature.

Start typing your method call:

```
self.requestLogin
```

and accept the auto-completion.

Now you see that Xcode has highlighted the callback part; click once on it to select it then hit ENTER, Xcode will automatically format the call properly like this:

```
self.requestLogin(self.settings.webServerLoginURL, { (myDictionary) -> () in
    println(myDictionary)
})
```

Comment: Ok, I've done exactly what you wrote but I think that the app crashes because the iOS simulator stops and what I read in the console is "(lldb)"...what does that mean?

Comment: so, if I read it on the console it means that an error occurred?

Comment: Yes. Xcode stops at the crash and opens the debugger for you to debug your app. You can then use commands like "po myDictionary" to view the objects contents. Xcode also lists the accessible objects visually in the panel at the left of the debugger. Google "xcode lldb swift", it's not necessarily complicated to learn it (there's just a lot). WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#409