# Swift: How to use NSURLSession to query external database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

I am writing this question because I am in a big difficulty in understanding how to implement a simple basic authentication login with Swift.

The first screen of my app is a simple form with text fields (username and password) and a Sign In button. In my LoginViewController.swift file I linked the button to this:

```
@IBAction func doLogin(sender : AnyObject) {
}
```

The probem now is that I don't know how to go on. I have a local server in MAMP where there is this file.php querying a database and which works perfectly:

```
<?php

$deep="";
require_once($deep."class/config.php");
$sistema = new config($deep);

if( isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"]) ) {
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($sistema->dbConn,$_GET["username"]);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($sistema->dbConn,$_GET["password"]);
    $userL=$sistema->user->allAdmin("WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' ");

    echo json_encode($userL);
}

?>
```

So how can I perform a GET request to this file? I suppose I need to create a URL with user data like this form:

```
http://localhost:8888/excogitoweb/loginM.php?username=lorenzo&password=lorenzo
```

but then I don't know how to go on. How can I perform this request to retrieve that JSON content? And how can I check that JSON content in order to understand if the sign in procedure has succeeded or has not?
I have watched many tutorials in youtube, overall [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ixk93yx-v28) but even if I copy the code they show I always get compilation errors...

Comment: Authentication is not simple, it is difficult to get correct. If this is a real app where authentication is important get help from a domain expert, it is very hard to get correct and very easy to have one small flaw that breaks the security.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32205126/451475) by the same OP 2 hours ago.

Comment: It is not so important...I would just need a basic authentication, as simpler as possible. I just want to perform an HTTT GET request to that file and check if the returned JSON data contain the user (with that username and password)...nothing more. Is it so difficult?

Comment: wait I will write you the code you need

Comment: ooh...thank you. I would appreciate it really...will you write in an answer?

Comment: Sending login credentials via an http request in the query string is very insecure.

Comment: I know... do you have any other suggestion? That was just to begin...then I would try to fix things better

Comment: Security is al about increasing the work factor (how hard) to breach the security. Some things that increase work factor: put the credentials in a POST, use https, pin the ssl certificate, use the latest TLS (1.2 at the moment), perfect forward security, etc. What needs to be done is determine how much security is required. What is the value of a security breach to the use, the site owner, the attacker all in cash and reputation. There is a point of diminishing returns, find it and secure to that point. I know security people who will not trust https in the best case.

Comment: well, this is just an iOS app I am trying to develop for "Mobile applications" exam so its usage it most of all academic... So, I think that use POST instead of GET could be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a "normal" GET request you need a NSURLRequest with your url... Its just like this:

```
if let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/excogitoweb/loginM.php?username=lorenzo&password=lorenzo") as NSURL? {
    let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let responseJSON: [String: String] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? [String: String] {
            ///Here you can handle the responded JSON
        }
    })
    urlSession.resume()
}
```

Don't forget, you are on a background Task when you handle the responded JSON... If you want to do some UI Stuff there you will need to dispatch it to the mein queue

Also a would recommend you doing HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET for such things

**UPDATE**

```
if let responseJSON: [[String: String]] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? [[String: String]] {
                ///Here you can handle the responded JSON
            }
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think that I forgot to write that the JSON format I get back from the php file is like that: [{"id":"8","nome":"Lorenzo","cognome":"Vinci","email":"silent.lory@gmail.com","username":"lorenzo","password":"lorenzo","auth":"Utente"}]

Comment: does it work with what you wrote? or shall I get only a json with username and password?

Comment: No the JSON you posted is a JSONArray... I will write you an update in my answer how to get this working...

Comment: [String: String] = Dictionary where key and value are strings (or JSON Object)... [[String: String]] = Array containing Dictionaries where key and value are strings (or JSON Array)

Comment: No problem mate, if you need some further help, just write me :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, at last I made it work. I'm very very ignorant and new about Swift and XCode. It was very kind of yours. Thank you from heart :) would you please give me your email? Should I still be getting insane with something, I could write to you...

Comment: I think I have another question for you: I put the code you gave me inside a method and I would like that method to return true if the login was ok, false otherwise. The problem is that the NSURLSession takes some time to finish and thus my method always return the initialized variable to false...do you know how to wait?

Comment: You need to set up a completionHandler Closure, or a Delegate... I will write you an Update of the code above

Comment: Here is a Gist with a solution of your Problem... https://gist.github.com/DennisWeidmann/f09c8b51df3f36a4bd50